# Devise Sign-up Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have my sign-up form on the home page of my Rails webapp and I was wondering how I could have the sign-up errors show up on that page instead of on the `/users/sign_up` page.  I tried moving the `devise_error_message!` block into my home page, but nothing shows up when the user is redirected to the home page after a failed sign-up.

Since `devise_error_messages` renders the errors on the `/users/sign_up` page -- why do they not show up on the homepage when I call it there?

Answer (score 0):

May be the "resource" attribute expected by devise helper methods could not be resolved to any value. Also, you should not redirect the user but just render the home page with errors. I am not sure how the models are transferred when rendered.

You can have a custom_devise_error_messages in your home page helper class:

```
def custom_devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    sentence = I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                      :count => resource.errors.count,
                      :resource => resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)

    html = <<-HTML
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>
      <ul style="padding:0; margin: 0; padding-left: 8px;">#{messages}</ul>
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
```

Also, from your sign up action method, instead of `redirect_to :path_or_url` use `render :action_name`.